# A switching mechanism which when fails should fail open to cut off the power to the load

Tags: mosfet, relay, switching, failure

I am working on a circuit design where a heater (10 Watts) load is switched ON and OFF using a relay. 
The relay is in turn switched ON  and OFF from N-MOSFET.
MOSFET is switched ON and OFF using a Micro-controller and an Opto-Isolator.
Our concern is that in case of MOSFET failing short/closed the relay will always be ON and the heater will stay ON.
Is there any way in the switching circuit design to cut off the power in case of MOSFET failing short? Or is there a way that MOSFET always fails OPEN?

Thanks in advance for your time and help.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQlh0Q.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: A  thermistor, pot and FET switch with another driver for hysteresis is generally adequate, but a secondary switch to latch OTP power off, if needed would need a secondary switch with memory.

Comment: The mosfet won't last long with no flyback diode across that relay...

Comment: And it's not just the MOSFET... what happens if D1 fails short, or the relay fuses itself closed...

Comment: @Trevor if D1 has a zener voltage smaller than the breakdown of the mosfet, that should be fine. Yes, still I would put a flyback diode instead of D1.

Comment: @Almeida If you're worried about that FET failing in short, then you could add another in series...  Yes, this might fail too, but what's the probability then?

Comment: A thermal fuse is a good candidate for over temp protection

Comment: I missed the flyback diode while creating a schematic here. We are definitely adding it across the relay coil.

Answer (score 1):

In high-reliability (like automotive) applications the Central Processing Unit usually employs checks on critical circuitry, which requires additional GPIOs, to watch if the command to a sensor or some action circuit gets executed properly. In this case if M1 fails with short, and CPU commands it to be OFF, the GPIO input will remain low, indicating fault condition. Then the CPU can turn corresponding power rail off (for which it should have another power gate to control). Likewise, if the M1 fails with OPEN, the same watch mechanism will detect the "open" fault.

Comment: Thanks Ali Chen! We have few spare GPIO to sense the fault condition and to control an additional switch for power rail.